# typescript nativescript carousel not working

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to simulate a carousel on my home page with my featured elements. It is getting the featured elements but the last ActivityIndicator in my html doesn't stop and I cannot swipe to the other elements.

I am new to nativescript and typescript

This is my home.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

//import { TNSFontIconService } from 'nativescript-ngx-fonticon';
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { View } from "ui/core/view";
import { SwipeGestureEventData, SwipeDirection } from "ui/gestures";
import * as enums from "ui/enums";

import { Cabin } from '../shared/cabin';
import { CabinService } from '../services/cabin.service';
import { House } from '../shared/house';
import { HouseService } from '../services/house.service';
import { Ecoactivity } from '../shared/ecoactivity';
import { EcoactivityService } from '../services/ecoactivity.service';
import { DrawerPage } from '../shared/drawer/drawer.page';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    // styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent extends DrawerPage implements OnInit {

    cabin: Cabin;
    house: House;
    ecoactivity: Ecoactivity;
    cabinErrMess: string;
    houseErrMess: string;
    ecoactivityErrMess: string;

    showLeftCard: boolean = true;
    showMiddleCard: boolean = false;
    showRightCard: boolean = false;
    leftCard: View;
    middleCard: View;
    rightCard: View;



    constructor(private cabinservice: CabinService,
        private houseservice: HouseService,
        private ecoactivityservice: EcoactivityService,
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private page: Page,
        @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL) {
        super(changeDetectorRef);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cabinservice.getFeaturedCabin()
            .subscribe(cabin => this.cabin = cabin,
                errmess => this.cabinErrMess = <any>errmess);
        this.houseservice.getFeaturedHouse()
            .subscribe(house => this.house = house,
                errmess => this.houseErrMess= <any>errmess);
        this.ecoactivityservice.getFeaturedEcoactivity()
            .subscribe(ecoactivity => this.ecoactivity = ecoactivity,
                errmess => this.ecoactivityErrMess = <any>errmess);
    }


    onSwipe(args: SwipeGestureEventData) {
        console.log("Swipe Direction: " + args.direction);

        if (args.direction === SwipeDirection.left) {
            this.animateLeft();
        }
        else if (args.direction === SwipeDirection.right) {
            this.animateRight();
        }
    }

    animateLeft() {

        if (this.cabin && this.house && this.ecoactivity) {
            this.leftCard = this.page.getViewById<View>('leftCard');
            this.middleCard = this.page.getViewById<View>('middleCard');
            this.rightCard = this.page.getViewById<View>('rightCard');

            if (this.showLeftCard) {
                this.rightCard.animate({
                    translate: { x: 2000, y: 0 }
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.leftCard.animate({
                            translate: { x: -2000, y: 0 },
                            duration: 500,
                            curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                        })
                            .then(() => {
                                this.showLeftCard = false;
                                this.showMiddleCard = true;
                                this.middleCard.animate({
                                    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                                    duration: 500,
                                    curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                                });
                            });
                    });
            }
            else if (this.showMiddleCard) {
                this.leftCard.animate({
                    translate: { x: 2000, y: 0 },
                    duration: 500
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.middleCard.animate({
                            translate: { x: -2000, y: 0 },
                            duration: 500,
                            curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                        })
                            .then(() => {
                                this.showMiddleCard = false;
                                this.showRightCard = true;
                                this.rightCard.animate({
                                    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                                    duration: 500,
                                    curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                                });
                            });
                    });
            }
            else if (this.showRightCard) {
                this.middleCard.animate({
                    translate: { x: 2000, y: 0 },
                    duration: 500
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.rightCard.animate({
                            translate: { x: -2000, y: 0 },
                            duration: 500,
                            curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                        })
                            .then(() => {
                                this.showRightCard = false;
                                this.showLeftCard = true;
                                this.leftCard.animate({
                                    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                                    duration: 500
                                });
                            });
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    animateRight() {

        if (this.cabin && this.house && this.ecoactivity) {
            this.leftCard = this.page.getViewById<View>('leftCard');
            this.middleCard = this.page.getViewById<View>('middleCard');
            this.rightCard = this.page.getViewById<View>('rightCard');

            if (this.showLeftCard) {
                this.middleCard.animate({
                    translate: { x: -2000, y: 0 },
                    duration: 500
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.leftCard.animate({
                            translate: { x: 2000, y: 0 },
                            duration: 500,
                            curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                        })
                            .then(() => {
                                this.showLeftCard = false;
                                this.showRightCard = true;
                                this.rightCard.animate({
                                    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                                    duration: 500,
                                    curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                                });
                            });
                    });
            }
            else if (this.showMiddleCard) {
                this.rightCard.animate({
                    translate: { x: -2000, y: 0 },
                    duration: 500
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.middleCard.animate({
                            translate: { x: 2000, y: 0 },
                            duration: 500,
                            curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                        })
                            .then(() => {
                                this.showMiddleCard = false;
                                this.showLeftCard = true;
                                this.leftCard.animate({
                                    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                                    duration: 500,
                                    curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                                });
                            });
                    });
            }
            else if (this.showRightCard) {
                this.leftCard.animate({
                    translate: { x: -2000, y: 0 },
                    duration: 500
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.rightCard.animate({
                            translate: { x: 2000, y: 0 },
                            duration: 500,
                            curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
                        })
                            .then(() => {
                                this.showRightCard = false;
                                this.showMiddleCard = true;
                                this.middleCard.animate({
                                    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                                    duration: 500
                                });
                            });
                    });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is my home.component.html

```
    <StackLayout tkMainContent (swipe)="onSwipe($event)">
    <GridLayout horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top" rows="*" columns="*" height="95%">
        <GridLayout id="leftCard" row="0" margin="5" rows="* auto" columns="*" *ngIf="cabin" [visibility]="showLeftCard ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'"
            class="border">
            <Image row="0" stretch="aspectFill" [src]="BaseURL + cabin.image"></Image>
            <StackLayout padding="10" row="1">
                <Label class="h2" [text]="cabin.name"></Label>
                <Label class="body" [text]="cabin.description" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator busy="true" *ngIf="!(cabin || cabinErrMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
        <Label *ngIf="cabinErrMess" [text]="'Error: ' + cabinErrMess"></Label>
        <GridLayout id="middleCard" row="0" margin="5" rows="* auto" columns="*" *ngIf="house" [visibility]="showMiddleCard ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'"
            class="border">
            <Image row="0" stretch="aspectFill" [src]="BaseURL + house.image"></Image>
            <StackLayout padding="10" row="1">
                <Label class="h2" [text]="house.name"></Label>
                <Label class="body" [text]="house.description" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator busy="true" *ngIf="!(house || houseErrMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
        <Label *ngIf="houseErrMess" [text]="'Error: ' + houseErrMess"></Label>
        <GridLayout id="rightCard" row="0" margin="5" rows="* auto" columns="*" *ngIf="ecoactivity" [visibility]="showRightCard ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'"
            class="border">
            <Image row="0" stretch="aspectFill" [src]="BaseURL + ecoactivity.image"></Image>
            <StackLayout padding="10" row="1">
                <Label class="h2" [text]="ecoactivity.name"></Label>
                <Label class="h3" [text]="ecoactivity.designation"></Label>
                <Label class="body" [text]="ecoactivity.description" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator busy="true" *ngIf="!(ecoactivity || ecoactivityErrMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
        <Label *ngIf="ecoactivityErrMess" [text]="'Error: ' + ecoactivityErrMess"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: `ecoactivity` / `ecoactivityErrMess` variables seems never declared in your component?

Comment: I do initialize them. I updated my question dont know how that part got deleted

Comment: Instead of doing `*ngIf` just bind the `busy` attribute to the condition. By default Activity Indicator will relayout and be eliminated from UI when `busy` is set to false.